# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'FLAGS') discord,js v13.0

Tags: javascript

My code was workin fine, but now i keep getting this error:

```
intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_VOICE_STATES, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES, Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS]
                  ^
```

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'FLAGS')

The part of the code:

```
const { Player, QueryType } = require("discord-player");
const Discord = require('discord.js');

const client = new Discord.Client({
    intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_VOICE_STATES, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES, Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS]
});
const prefix = '*';

const fs = require('fs');

client.commands = new Discord.Collection();
```

Comment: Where does `Intents` come from or is supposed to come from? Did you miss a `require` somewhere?

Comment: It's not, it was working perfectly 5 days ago

Comment: See https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/intents.html#the-intents-bitfield